# Can I access the expression property of an SSIS object programmatically?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a Flat File Connection Manager set up in an SSIS package that is doing a daily import of data.  I wanted to set up a script task / object which checks to make sure the ConnectionString property of that connection manager is set to something.  Wondering if this is possible!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to store the connection string in a `variable`, lets here call it **ConnectionToSomeServer**.

Select the connection in the **connection manager** and within the properties open the **Expressions** by clicking on the `[...]`.

[image: Connectionmanage Connection Properties]

Here you can set the `ConnectionString` to your defined variable.

[image: Connection Expression Editor]

In the script task you can access the variable holding the connection string like this:

```
var connectionString = (string) Dts.Variables["ConnectionToSomeServer"].Value;
```

Now you can check if the connection is valid within the script task:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        // connection is valid
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        // connection is not valid
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        return;
    }
}
```

You can also manage the connection in the `Project.params`, which has the advantage to be configurable using `Environments` and referencing the value of **ConnectionToSomeServer** variable to the project parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  Think this will help me.

Comment: The default connection strings for SQL Server are usually OleDbConnection. Just look out for what kind of connection you are making. If you are used to SqlClient there are some differences. Especially in parameter usage.

Comment: And what if the expression was not a single variable? There is a simpler way to do that. Check the other answers. @KeithL even if it is an OLeDBConnection you can use `Dts.Connections` property to read the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are wanting to do this, but you will need to create a variable that is used to populate the Connection Manager's ConnectionString property. From there, you can access the package variable in the script task to perform whatever inspection that you want on it. Though, to my knowledge, it is not possible to directly tap into SSIS task/component properties via C# in a script task.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Dts` namespace within a script task to access the connection manager from Dts.Connections` property:

```
 string myFlatFileConnection = 
                Dts.Connections["Test Flat File Connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) ;
```

*Note that the connection manager name is case sensitive*

**Reference**

- [Connecting to Data Sources in the Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/connecting-to-data-sources-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017#connections-example)